# Generating file on Express server and initiating client-side download prompt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, excel, reactjs, exceljs

I am working with the ExcelJS module to generate an Excel file, but am having difficulty achieving the desired flow.

What I'd like to have is:

1. User clicks a button on the front-end (built with React) to download an Excel file. This triggers a fetch('/downloads/results') which is the back-end endpoint for the file creation and serving.
2. The file is generated and gets sent to /downloads/results as the res of the get request.
3. The user gets a download prompt from the browser on the front-end so they can decide where to save it.

What is happening now is that instead of the user being prompted on the front-end, Node is just creating the Excel file in the same folder as the server file. The bit of code that is creating the file is "workbook.xlsx.writeFile('Project.xlsx')"

My current code is below.

Relevant server-side code block:

```
function generateSpreadsheet(req, res) {

    const workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    workbook.creator = 'Project';
    workbook.created = new Date();

    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("Definitions");

    worksheet.columns = [
        { header: 'Word', key: 'word', width: 36 },
        { header: 'Definition', key: 'def', width: 120 }
    ];

    worksheet.addRows(storedResults);

    workbook.xlsx.writeFile('Project.xlsx');

}

app.get('/downloads/results', (req, res) => {
    try {
        generateSpreadsheet();
    } catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
})
```

Relevant front-end code:

```
renderDownloadButton() {
    if (this.state.queriesList.length > 0) {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.download}>
                Export Results
            </button>
        )
    }
}

download() {
    fetch('/downloads/results');
}
```

I've been researching most of the past few days but haven't come to a satisfactory solution.

I tried playing around with having the generateSpreadsheet function return a stream, thinking I could then pipe that to the res in app.get but I was getting tripped up a bit.

Thanks for any insight/direction you can provide!